# Python - Group arrays by limiting number of elements in sub array

Tags: python, arrays, list, grouping

```
m = [
    ('Mon', [1,2,4,32,23]),
    ('Tue', [1,7]),
    ('Wed', [11,9,6,4,32,1]),
    ('Thu', [8]),
    ('Fri', [344,3,2,0])
]
```

How to group the arrays like this:

```
l = 3
m = [
    [('Mon', [1,2,4])],

    [('Mon', [32,23]),
    ('Tue', [1])],

    [('Tue', [7]),
    ('Wed', [11,9])],

    [('Wed', [6,4,32])],

    [('Wed', [1]),
    ('Thu', [8]),
    ('Fri', [344])],

    [('Fri', [3,2,0])]
]

#######

l = 10
m = [
    [('Mon', [1,2,4,32,23]), 
    ('Tue', [1,7]),
    ('Wed', [11,9,6])],

    [('Wed', [4,32,1]),
    ('Thu', [8]),
    ('Fri', [344,3,2,0])]
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are your rules for splitting up the lists? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: There is no one builtin function that do such operation. Although, you can iterate through the main array, apply your rules for split to every element and yield the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
from itertools import islice
from pprint import pprint

def split(seq, l):
    count = sum(len(x[1]) for x in m)
    seq = [(a, iter(b)) for a, b in seq]
    while count > 0:
        group = []
        current_count = 0
        for x in seq:
            data = list(islice(x[1], l-current_count))
            count -= len(data)
            if data:
                if current_count  + len(data) > l:
                    yield group
                    group = [(x[0], data)]
                    current_count = len(data)
                    break
                else:
                    group.append((x[0], data))
                    current_count += len(data)
        yield group

out1 = list(split(m, 3))
out2 = list(split(m, 10))
pprint(out1)
pprint(out2)
```

**Output:**

```
[[('Mon', [1, 2, 4])],
 [('Mon', [32, 23]), ('Tue', [1])],
 [('Tue', [7]), ('Wed', [11, 9])],
 [('Wed', [6, 4, 32])],
 [('Wed', [1]), ('Thu', [8]), ('Fri', [344])],
 [('Fri', [3, 2, 0])]]

[[('Mon', [1, 2, 4, 32, 23]), ('Tue', [1, 7]), ('Wed', [11, 9, 6])],
 [('Wed', [4, 32, 1]), ('Thu', [8]), ('Fri', [344, 3, 2, 0])]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m = [
    ('Mon', [1,2,4,32,23]),
    ('Tue', [1,7]),
    ('Wed', [11,9,6,4,32,1]),
    ('Thu', [8]),
    ('Fri', [344,3,2,0])
]

maxsize = 3

output = []
for day, arr in m:
    thelist = []
    for num in arr:
        thelist.append(num)
        if len(thelist)==maxsize:
            output.append( (day, thelist) )
            thelist = []
    if len(thelist):
        output.append( (day, thelist) )


import pprint
pprint.pprint(output)
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected result

Comment: You're right, and I just did a small edit to preserve the tuples. There is one more thing though: the OP doesn't explain what is the rule for ordering the sublists in the output list.

Comment: Are you sure it works? It looks like totally wrong

Comment: Thanks, damn it I messed it up in my edit! Sorry looking into it.

Comment: ok fixed it but didn't figure out the sublist stuff. My vote goes to Ashwini

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, izip
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> i = 3

>>> weekday_number = ((weekday, number) for (weekday, numbers) in m for number in numbers)
>>> grouped_by_i_elements = izip(*[weekday_number]*i)
>>> [[(key, [number for weekday,number in elements_it]) for key,elements_it in groupby(group, itemgetter(0))] for group in grouped_by_i_elements]
[[('Mon', [1, 2, 4])],
 [('Mon', [32, 23]), ('Tue', [1])],
 [('Tue', [7]), ('Wed', [11, 9])],
 [('Wed', [6, 4, 32])],
 [('Wed', [1]), ('Thu', [8]), ('Fri', [344])],
 [('Fri', [3, 2, 0])]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m = [
    ('Mon', [1,2,4,32,23]),
    ('Tue', [1,7]),
    ('Wed', [11,9,6,4,32,1]),
    ('Thu', [8]),
    ('Fri', [344,3,2,0])
]

# at first we change the data structure like this
tuple_list = [ (day, number) for day, numbers in m for number in numbers ]

tuple_list
Out[22]:
[('Mon', 1),
 ('Mon', 2),
 ('Mon', 4),
...
 ('Fri', 3),
 ('Fri', 2),
 ('Fri', 0)]

# now we can group l of them
l = 3
subgroups = [ tuple_list[e:e+l] for e in range(0,len(tuple_list),l)]
subgroups
Out[23]:
[[('Mon', 1), ('Mon', 2), ('Mon', 4)],
 [('Mon', 32), ('Mon', 23), ('Tue', 1)],
 [('Tue', 7), ('Wed', 11), ('Wed', 9)],
 [('Wed', 6), ('Wed', 4), ('Wed', 32)],
 [('Wed', 1), ('Thu', 8), ('Fri', 344)],
 [('Fri', 3), ('Fri', 2), ('Fri', 0)]]
In [24]:

# To get the old data structure, we can group each subgroup
# by its day of week
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
subgroups_b = [ 
                [
                 (key, [number for day, number in grouper])
                      for key, grouper in groupby(subgroup, key=itemgetter(0))
                ]
                for subgroup in subgroups 

            ]
subgroups_b
Out[25]:
[[('Mon', [1, 2, 4])],
 [('Mon', [32, 23]), ('Tue', [1])],
 [('Tue', [7]), ('Wed', [11, 9])],
 [('Wed', [6, 4, 32])],
 [('Wed', [1]), ('Thu', [8]), ('Fri', [344])],
 [('Fri', [3, 2, 0])]]
```

Comment: @thefourtheye I just noticed the last step is wrong, I think...

Comment: @thefourtheye: 1. The data are sorted since I use lists in each step and I generate a sorted list at the beginning. 2. I think I did not misread it, just posted a half-baked version...

Answer (score 0):

These two functions will solve the problem:

```
import itertools

def custom_len(list_of_tuples):
    tmp_l = [t[1] for t in list_of_tuples]
    return len(list(itertools.chain(*tmp_l)))

def group_in_lists(list_of_tuples, max_list_size):
    tmp_list = []
    for x in list_of_tuples:
        tmp_list.append((x[0], []))

        for y in x[1]:
            if custom_len(tmp_list) >= max_list_size:
                yield list(tmp_list)
                tmp_list = [(x[0], [y])]
            else:
                tmp_list[-1][1].append(y)

        if custom_len(tmp_list) >= max_list_size:
            yield list(tmp_list)
            tmp_list = []

    if tmp_list != []:
        yield tmp_list
```

Testing the functions:

```
m = [
    ('Mon', [1,2,4,32,23]),
    ('Tue', [1,7]),
    ('Wed', [11,9,6,4,32,1]),
    ('Thu', [8]),
    ('Fri', [344,3,2,0])
]
l = 3

test_output = group_in_lists(m, l)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(list(test_output))
```